# How to clean canvas area by finger

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, paint

i have two imageviews one is gallery image and one is transparent image drawn throw canvas on second image and i want to clean that transparent image by finger

i trying to do like 
Link:https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steam.doodle&hl=en

i tryd below code

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

```
ImageView image,transimage;
 Paint paint;
 Bitmap bitmap,resultbitmap;
 Canvas canvas;
 Button clear;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    transimage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

    //Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.saibaba);
       Bitmap mBitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snw);
       Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap2.getWidth(), mBitmap2.getHeight(), mBitmap2.getConfig());
       Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
       canvas.setBitmap(bmOverlay);
       paint=new Paint();
         paint.setAlpha(200);
      // canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
       canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap2, 0, 0, paint);
       transimage.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);
```

}
}

How to clean the canvas by finger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set Color= Transparent on the method onDraw. This is the tested code and is working.

```
 @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                if(isEraseMode){
                    paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    canvas.drawPath(eraserPath, erasePaint);
                     //canvas.save();
                }else{
                    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                     canvas.restore();
                }
                 canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

                    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);

            }
```

Hope this would help you..:)

Comment: @priyanaka i'm not getting any idea